# Differential operators on compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

First I should apologise if this is a bit of a vague question, but I could not find any references for the explicit construction.

I've seen it stated in several places that a differential operator on sections of a vector bundle $E$ over a compact manifold $M$ can be extended to a Fredholm operator between appropriate Sobolev spaces. However, I am unsure how exactly this is done.

1) How does one define the appropriate Sobolev spaces? I understand that ordinarily (for functions on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$) this is done via weak derivatives, but what would be the analogous thing to do on a manifold? How similar are these two constructions in terms of their respective properties (eg is completeness proved in different ways)?

2) Once the $H^i$ are defined, how do we construct a Fredholm operator based on our differential operator $\Gamma(E)\rightarrow\Gamma(E)$? Is it true that the index (which, I think, is only defined for Fredholm operators) of this Fredholm operator is equal to the difference in dimension of kernel and cokernel of our differential operator?

3) In the case that $d: \Gamma(\Lambda^*(T^*M))\rightarrow \Gamma(\Lambda^*(T^*M))$, I'm assuming $d$ determines an operator $H^1\rightarrow H^0$. What are $H^0$ and $H^1$ in this case?

I'd appreciate any comments, explicit constructions, or suggestions for references on this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Partitions of unity and local trivializations. Do the standard Sobolev norms and add them. This will depend on the choice of trivializations; up to equivariance it will not.

2) With he above norm, you can define Sobolev completions of the appropriate spaces of sections. Because locally your operator is just a differential operator in the standard sense, you can continuously extend it to the completion.

3) I don't really understand the question. They're the spaces of $L^2$ and $L^2_1$ sections of the appropriate bundles, where a function being $L^2$ or whatever is defined with respect to a local trivialization.